# Using xUnit and Moq to test assertions in ASP.NET C# service

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, moq, xunit

I'm trying to test if the resulting list is not null and matches what is expected from the service method.
I am using xUnit and Moq in ASP.NET C#.
I am not able to get the expected results (it should fail with the given parameters).

This is my test:

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(1, "2022")]
public async Task GetLevelsAsync_ReturnsLevelList(int appId, string year)
{
    //Arrange
    IOptions<Settings> options = Options.Create(set);
    _geoRepository.Setup(g => g.GetLevelsByYear(appId, year)).ReturnsAsync(GetLevelsYear2022());
    GeoService geo = new GeoService(_geoRepository.Object, _loggerGeoService.Object, options);

    //Act
    List<Level> result = await geo.GetLevelsAsync(appId, year);

    //Assert
    Assert.NotNull(result);
    Assert.Equal(GetLevelsYear2022().Count(), result.Count());
    Assert.Equal(
        GetLevelsYear2022().OrderByDescending(l => l.Id),
        result.OrderByDescending(l => l.Id),
        new LevelEqualityComparer());
    Assert.NotEqual(
        GetLevelsYear2021().OrderByDescending(l => l.Id),
        result.OrderByDescending(l => l.Id),
        new LevelEqualityComparer());
}

public class LevelEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Level>
{
    public bool Equals(Level x, Level y)
    {
        if (x is null || y is null) return false;
        return x.Id == y.Id;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Level obj)
    {
        return obj.Id;
    }
}
```

This is my controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<List<Level>>> GetLevelsAsync([FromRoute] string CountryCode, string Year)
{
    int appId = ICCode.FromName(CountryCode).Id;

    var result = await _geoService.GetLevelsAsync(appId, Year);

    return result;
}
```

This is my service:

```
public async Task<List<Level>> GetLevelsAsync(int appId, string year)
{

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(year))
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(year));

    var result = await _geoRepository.GetLevelsByYear(appId, year);

    return result;
}
```

This is my repository:

```
public async Task<List<Level>> GetLevelsByYear(int appId, string year)
{

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(year))
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(year));

    var result = new List<Level>();

    var parameters = new { AppId = appId, Year = year };

    string sql = @"SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE AppId = @AppId AND DataYear = @Year";

    using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(_settings.SqlServerConnString))
    {
        try
        {
            result = db.Query<Level>(sql, parameters).ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.LogError(e, "Error querying levels by year", new { appId, year });
            throw;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

This is my Level class:

```
public class Level
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Year { get; set; }

    public string Code { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int GeometryType { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You have two `List<Level>` and you're comparing `ToString()` for both of them. `List<T>` doesn't override `ToString()`, so it will always return the name of the type. It won't be different because the lists contain different things. It looks like what you want is to compare two `List<Level>` and see if they contain equivalent items. We can help if you post the `Level` class so we can suggest ways to compare them.

Comment: It might become clearer if you change the last `Assert.Equal` to `Assert.NotEqual`. Then the test will fail, and if you click on the failed test it will show you what it was comparing.

Comment: @ScottHannen I have posted the `Level` class to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your service returns `List<Level>`.

If you call `GetLevelList().ToString()` the result is always going to show the name of the type because `List<T>` doesn't override `ToString()`. That means that regardless of what the list contains, `ToString()` will always return the same result.

It appears that what you want is to compare two `List<Level>` and see if they contain the same result.

How you do that depends somewhat on how you compare two instances of `Level` to determine whether they are equivalent. You could determine that they're equivalent if all of their properties are equal. Or if these represent records from a database you could determine that two are the same if they have the same `Id`.

There are different ways to do this. Here's one.

First create an `IEqualityComparer` that compares two instances of `Level` to see if they are equivalent using criteria that you define. (This probably belongs in your test project.)

```cs
public class LevelEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Level>
{
    public bool Equals(Level x, Level y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, null)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(y, null)) return false;
        if (x.GetType() != y.GetType()) return false;
        return x.Id == y.Id;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Level obj)
    {
        return obj.Id;
    }
}
```

That looks like a lot of typing. Resharper (developer productivity tool) generated it for me. For practical purposes you could shorten it to

```cs
public class LevelEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Level>
{
    public bool Equals(Level x, Level y)
    {
        if(x is null || y is null) return false;
        return x.Id == y.Id;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Level obj)
    {
        return obj.Id;
    }
}
```

Now, if you have two collections of `Level`, you'd want to see if they are the same. You can do this:

```cs
Assert.Equal(
    levels1.OrderBy(l=>l.Id), 
    levels2.OrderBy(l=>l.Id), 
    new LevelEqualityComparer());
```

This will compare the two collections and see if they contain the same items. It uses the `LevelEqualityComparer`, which means it will only look at the IDs to compare them. It sorts them because otherwise they could contain the same IDs in a different order, and they wouldn't match.

---

If wanted comparing `Level` by ID to be the default in all your code then you could define that within the `Level` class itself, like this:

```cs
public class Level : IEqualityComparer<Level>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Year { get; set; }

    public string Code { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int GeometryType { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Level x, Level y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, null)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(y, null)) return false;
        if (x.GetType() != y.GetType()) return false;
        return x.Id == y.Id;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Level obj)
    {
        return obj.Id;
    }
}
```

Then you wouldn't need the separate equality comparer class.

---

Or, what if you just wanted to compare the IDs, and that's never going to change? Then you could just skip the equality comparison and do this:

```cs
var levels1Ids = levels1.Select(l => l.Id).OrderBy(id => id);
var levels2Ids = levels2.Select(l => l.Id).OrderBy(id => id);
Assert.Equal(levels1Ids, levels2Ids);
```

I saved that for last because it doesn't cover as many scenarios, but it's easiest and what I would probably do.

It just gets the IDs from both collections, sorts them, and compares the two lists of IDs.

Comment: I have created the `IEqualityComparer` but I'm still not getting the expected result. I have the `year` parameter as `X` which should make the test fail.

Comment: When comparing the expected result and the actual result, they are the same when they shouldn't be. `GetLevelList()` returns the list for `year: "2022"`. The `result` using the parameter `year: "X"` should not be the same as the `GetLevelList()`. Why is the `result` returning the same list when it's using different parameters?

Comment: As written the comparer determines that two `Level`s are "equal" if they have the same ID. If you want it to do the comparison using year you could change the comparer to use that instead of the ID.

Comment: I want to compare the ID's. The 2 lists should have different ID's. `GetLevelList()` and `result` should not be the same. If I use parameter `year = 2022` for `result`, then it is equivalent to `GetLevelList()`. Since I'm using parameter `year = X` for `result`, I am expecting an empty or null `result` but it is the same as `GetLevelList()`. Please let me know if this is unclear, thank you.

Comment: The comparison will accurately tell you if you've got levels with identical IDs. At this point it could be that the test is correctly telling you that the code is doing something different from what you expect.

Comment: I am trying to compare 2 lists. 1 list is not null and has ID's. The other list is null and has no ID's. The list that is not null and has ID's is coming from `GetLevelList()` which I created for this test. The list that I am expecting to be null and has no ID's is coming from `var result = await geo.GetLevelsAsync(appId, year)` where `year = X`. However, when comparing, the `result` is not null and has the same data as  `GetLevelList()`. Are you able to see what I am doing wrong? I want `result` to be null since I am using an invalid parameter `year = X`.

Comment: I'm trying, but it's hard to follow. If you have two lists - one is null and one has values, and you do `Assert.Equal(list1, list2)`, it should fail. The only way it can pass is if they both have values and those values are the same. If you set a breakpoint on the assert and look at the two lists that you're comparing, what do you see?